# How do I retrieve all mobile devices?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I want to retrieve all mobile devices under my G Suite domain. So I tried on "Try this API" with an account that was granted the "Super Admin" role.

I can retrieve 109 devices on Admin Console.

- Admin Console - Devices - Mobile Devices
  https://admin.google.com/ac/devices/list?category=mobile

But, I can retrieve only 5 devices via API.

- Mobiledevices: list  |  Directory API  |  Google Developers
  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list?apix_params=%7B%22customerId%22%3A%22my_customer%22%7D

  - customerId = my_customer

Is it correct behavior?

How do I retrieve all mobile devices via API?

Comment: are you issuing this request from the super admin account of the domain?

Comment: Yes, I tried with an account that was granted the "Super Admin" role.

Comment: I have attempted to reproduce this issue with no success. I suggest you please contact [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) in order to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks @carlesgg97. 
Directory API is not related to core G Suite services. So, I came Stack Overflow. [G Suite API support - G Suite Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6103110?hl=en), [How to get help  |  Directory API  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/support)

I found this report. I commented and starred. (I found it before I posted to Stack Overflow.)  [Not all mobile devices are returned when call directory api (mobiledevices)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62124267)